# SQL _complex query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using sql server as data source.

In a table I have columns like `email 1, email2, email3`.

I need to write the query to search record in either field and display as New_email.

It has to search in `email1`, if it is null, then search in `email2` and then `email3`, the resulted record shows as `new_email`.

Comment: `'your email Id' in (email1,email2,email3)`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `COALESCE` with the `IN` operator. [Read more about the COALESCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)

```
SELECT
     COALESCE(email1,email2,email3,'defaultvalue') AS SelectedEMail
FROM
    tablename
WHERE
    'youremail@mail.com' IN(eamil1,eamil2,eamil3)
    --more conditions
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply select:

```
DECLARE @email NVARCHAR(50) = ''
SELECT @email AS Email
FROM TableName 
WHERE @email IN(EmailCol1, EmailCol2, EmailCol3)
```